# Get Image Link From HTML in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, html-parsing, windows-store-apps

I've tried to use HtmlAgilityPack, but it is not fully supported by WinRT,

The " `DocumentElement.SelectNodes` " does not work on WinRT

How Can I get An image link (src) from an HTML page ( or HTML string ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The " DocumentElement.SelectNodes " does not work on WinRT

Then use Linq. This is all I can do blindly

```
var imgLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                 .Select(img => img.Attributes["src"].Value)
                 .ToList();
```